# Will the Fermat's last theorem still hold if algebraic and transcendental numbers are introduced?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

This might seem as a wild thought and is also a wild thought that will the Fermat's last theorem still hold if algebraic and transcendental numbers are introduced?

What I mean to say is that will the equation $$x^a+y^a \neq z^a$$ still hold for some algebraic numbers $x,y,z$ and $a$ is transcendental with $a>2$.

Comment: Kinda related: If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are any nonconstant polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb C$, and $n\ge3$ is an integer, then $X^n+Y^n\ne Z^n$. (I might have misstated it. I also remember nothing of the proof.) This does not hold for $n=2$; a counterexample would be $(1-x^2)+(2x)^2=(1+x^2)^2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's find a solution for $x = y = 4$, $z = 5$. The equation $x^a + y^a = z^a$ is just $2^{2a+1} = 5^a$. Taking logarithms and solving for $a$ we find that $a = \frac{\log 2}{\log 5/4}$ is the desired solution.

I claim that $a$ is transcendental. For it's clearly irrational, and if it were algebraic, the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) would say that $\left(\frac 54\right)^a$ would be transcendental; but it's actually 2, which is hardly transcendental.

This same idea can be used to give infinitely many explicit counterexamples to your proposed generalization.

Comment: This is just a special case of Nate's answer, with a proof that the resulting $a$ is actually algebraic.

Answer (score 3):

Take any three positive integers $x < y < z$ such that $x^2 + y^2 > z^2$. The function $f(a) = x^a + y^a - z^a$ is positive at $2$, but eventually becomes negative since the $z^a$ term dominates.  Hence by the intermediate value theorem we get that $f(a) =0$ for some $a$.

Comment: Sorry but i require a to be transcendental and x,y,z to be algebraic

Comment: That says nothing about the transcendence of $a$.

Comment: @Rememberme integers are algebraic. Although it is fair that this says nothing about the transcendence of $a$. Of course I would be surprised if $a$ were algebraic here.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that@jgon

Comment: I mean if the $a$ ended up being algebraic, wouldn't that be strictly more interesting?

Comment: But transcendental numbers have an air of mystery about them so you don't know what you might end up with.